# Drupal 6 - user_profile_form not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm attempting to use the code below to display the 'Registration Information' group of my users profiles in Drupal 6.  When this code is executed, the field labels from the profile form are displayed, but the input fields are not.  The page source doesn't have the form tags.  This code works on other installations of D6 - so I'm confident it works.  Any ideas where to begin to debug?

```
global $user; 
$uid = $user->uid;
if ($uid > 0) {  
include_once drupal_get_path('module', 'user') . '/user.pages.inc';  
$profile =  profile_load_profile($user);
print(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'Registration Information'));
}
```

Comment: Drupal usually does things by machine names rather than title of an object...try changing `'Registration Information'` to `'registration_information'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using profile_load_profile() function, but then your not using that profile in the next line. Instead your using the global $user. I am guessing here, but aren't you loading profile because you need it in the next line?

So instead of:

```
print(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'Registration Information'));
```

Try:

```
print(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $profile, 'Registration Information'));
```

Comment: `profile_load_profile()` takes the `$user` argument by reference and adds fields to it. Assigning the return to `$profile` doesn't actually do anything as `profile_load_profile()` has no return value...`$user` is definitely the right object to be passing to `drupal_get_form()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  The only thing that ended up working was:

```
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
print user_edit($user, 'Registration Information');
```